# WARNING: Experimental features are turned on. Do not use experimental features on live deployments

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
```

I have a warning in my .sol files. I don't know what is the meaning of this warning. Can you help me for this?

warning in this line --> pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, experimental features can be unstable and produce unexpected and undocumented bugs - which you might not want in a production environment. Hence the warning.

---

This specific `ABIEncoderV2` was introduced in Solidity version 0.5, enabling use of nested arrays and mappings. In this Solidity version, the encoder's stability was marked as `experimental` (i.e. likely unstable).

Docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.5.17/layout-of-source-files.html#abiencoderv2

*Note that these docs are for a deprecated Solidity version 0.5.*

In the current Solidity version 0.8, the `ABIEncoderV2` encoder is stable and no longer experimental. So if you're compiling the project with the latest compiler version, you can freely remove the `pragma experimental` statement, which will also remove the warning.

Comment: Thank you so much for your all information. I understood the point. I upgraded the compiler version (lastest). And all warnings is gone.